# Recursively replaced element with editor (and back) breaks event listeners

Tags: javascript, jquery

Background: There are some values on my website which shall be editable via JavaScript and Ajax. The Ajax is working fine and I can edit values but after I saved the value I cannot edit it again without reloading the page.

I reduced the problem to this: The original element gets replaced with a HTML form. When the form is submitted the form itself is replaced by the new version of the display element, but the event listener is broken.

I put together some sample JS code ([JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J8Sa7/)) which doesn't work as I expect.

```
var text = $('<em/>').text('click me!');

text.click(function() {
    var button = $('<input type="button" value="Click me, too" />');

    button.click(function() {
        $('#container').html(text);
    });

    $('#container').html(button);
})

$('#container').html(text);
```

What shall happen:

1. current value displayed
2. after text `click`ed text replaced with form (text element saved for simplicity)
3. after button `click` text displayed again
4. `click` on text works again as in step 2 (doesn't work now)

Why is the `click` event lost when using the `text` object again?

Comment: `html(text)` overrides the element content...

Comment: @gdoron: That is what I wanted it to do. The original text is stored (in reality it's retrieved from server side again) and the button *shall* be removed and be replaced by the text (and vice versa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`.html()` method](http://api.jquery.com/html/) (re)sets the `innerHTML` property to a *text value*. These strings have no event listeners - I think that's a bug in jQuery that `.html()` accepts anything than [strings (and functions)](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2); in here your jQuery object seems to be even stringified.

To change the content to already existing DOM nodes, you will need to [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) the container (or [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) the text element) and [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) the button element.

Comment: It sounded promising and I could follow the logic but unfortunately it doesn't help. I change the JSfiddle to apply to your advice but the behaviour is the same:(

Comment: Uh, jQuery tries to be clever here. I should have read the docs instead of just linking them: [`.detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) will work: http://jsfiddle.net/J8Sa7/5/

Comment: The `.detach()` from your last comment worked very well. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

One option to make it work and not to rewrite the whole structure is to clone element with binded events:

```
text.click(function() {
    ...
    button.click(function() {
        $('#container').html(text.clone(true));
    });
    ...
})

$('#container').html(text.clone(true));
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/J8Sa7/2/

Comment: It work's, yay. Can you explain why the element needs to be explicitly cloned? I expected the element could be used inside the DOM several times or would be cloned correctly implicitly. However I see that it's not necessary for the button because it's created anew everytime the text is clicked, right?

Comment: Bonus: You indirectly suggest rewriting the whole structure. I am not really satisfied with the large bunch of nested JS functions (there are some more with the Ajax stuff) but I supposed this is how JS works. If you have some hint how to write it with less nesting, I'd appreciate.

Comment: @halo: Regarding bonus, for really dynamic elements (that can be added or removed) I'd prefer using [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (read about delegated-events approach). Here is one basic solution: http://jsfiddle.net/J8Sa7/4/. It works so that you don't need to bind events every time you add new element.

Comment: Thanks for the hint to delegated events. That's an interesting thing. But in this case I prefer having the events connected with the elements to save some overhead.